# why does printing a returned tuple differ from printing members of the tuple by index?

Tags: python, printing, tuples

I've got this function (see below) that accepts a few values and returns a tuple.  If I print the values of the tuple using indexes into it (e.g. tuple[0], tuple[1], etc.) then the value printed is correct.  But if I just print the tuple or print the function, then I get some crazy values (sometimes).

Here's the code:

```
import math

def getvector(x1,y1,length,angle):

    x1 = float(x1)
    y1 = float(y1)
    length = float(length)
    angle = float(angle)

    x2 = x1 + (length * math.cos(math.radians(angle)))
    y2 = y1 + (length * math.sin(math.radians(angle)))

    print "in getvector x2,y2 = (%f, %f)" % (x2,y2)

    return (x2,y2)


xy2 = getvector(0,0,4,270)
print "in main x2,y2 = (%f, %f)" % (xy2[0],xy2[1])
print getvector(0,0,4,270)
print "tuple =", xy2
```

And the result:

```
in getvector x2,y2 = (-0.000000, -4.000000)
in main x2,y2 = (-0.000000, -4.000000)
in getvector x2,y2 = (-0.000000, -4.000000)
(-7.3478807948841188e-16, -4.0)
tuple = (-7.3478807948841188e-16, -4.0)
```

Any idea what's going on??  Why are the values different when I print the tuple directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing with the `%f` format specification is showing your results with 7 significant digits.  Printing the tuple by itself is not - that's why you get the -7.3... number (which is very small, and close to zero).

Answer (score 3):

So here's what's happening:

When printing the values individually, you're printing them using a format string (%f), which prints numbers in floating point format (ie, up to about 7 significant digits). This part is correct.

When printing the values as part of a tuple, the tuple itself is responsible for producing its own string representation. When it creates a string representation of your values, it does not use the %f format string; instead, it simply calls `repr()` on the object. This results in no formatting and just gets the exact value, to the full 14 decimal places, of the number. Compare:

```
import math
>>> print "%f" % (0.0 + 4*math.cos(math.radians(270)))
-0.000000
>>> print repr(0.0 + 4*math.cos(math.radians(270)))
-7.3478807948841188e-16
```